# Is Scikit-Learn's classification report supposed to show samples with 0 support?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm running a text classification task and am using [`sklearn.metrics.classification_report`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html). I've noticed that there are many cases where labels with supports of 0 are also shown, but is this expected behavior?

To give a specific example, let's say that the task I have at hand has five labels `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`. I wanted to make sure that my model is able to train properly on label `0` and so I created a separate dataset containing only those labels. The classification report after the first epoch looks like this:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0     1.0000    0.8929    0.9434      9713
           1     0.0000    0.0000    0.0000         0
           2     0.0000    0.0000    0.0000         0
           3     0.0000    0.0000    0.0000         0

    accuracy                         0.8929      9713
   macro avg     0.2500    0.2232    0.2359      9713
weighted avg     1.0000    0.8929    0.9434      9713
```

As far as I know (and please correct me if I'm wrong), the labels shown on the left column are labels contained in `y_true`. So not only is the report not supposed to show `1`, `2`, and `3`, but it's also not showing `4` which it should if the behavior's supposed to be consistent.

I've checked my data and made sure that it only contains `0` so it's not a data issue, and I've also double checked to make sure I'm not swapping `y_true` and `y_pred` when calling the function.

Why does this behavior happen? And is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The labels on the left are the predicted labels. In other words, your model still predicts classes 1, 2 and 3 (but not 4) in some (about 11%) cases where it should ideally predict 0.

Edit: to be precise, `classification_report()` runs `sklearn.utils.multiclass.unique_labels()` on both `y_true` and `y_pred` (unless you specify a label list explicitly), which is the same as predicted labels in this case.

The rest just wraps `precision_recall_fscore_support()`. [The support is the number of occurrences of each class in `y_true`.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html)

Comment: Thanks. Seems like I misunderstood the function in general then. So a support of 0 would mean that the model made that prediction despite the label not being contained in `y_true`, right?

Comment: Exactly. Also, I have to correct my statement regarding labels a bit after looking into the source code, see my edit.

Comment: This is a few months old but I came back to ask a question out of more confusion. So there's no way to know how many of each class our model has predicted, right? Since the currently provided support only shows the number of each label in `y_true`.

Comment: Not via `classification_report()` I guess, since its basically just wraps `precision_recall_fscore_support()`. It can be trivially checked using something like `np.unique(return_counts=True)` though.

Comment: I find that a little surprising. Not sure about everyone else but I personally find myself having to look for # of predicted vs. # of true often in my day to day. Wonder why it wasn't included.

Comment: That sounds more like `confusion_matrix()` to me.

Comment: Yeah, I could calculate what I want via `confusion_matrix()`, but what I really want is to have the predicted numbers displayed with the classification report lol. Maybe I'll just write my own, it shouldn't be that hard.

Answer (score 0):

Classification report provides an outer join between predicted classless and the labels:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
y = [0,1,2,3]
y_hat = [0,0,0,4]
pd.DataFrame(classification_report(y, y_hat, output_dict=True)).T
```

output:

```
    precision   recall  f1-score    support
0   0.333333    1.00    0.500   1.00
1   0.000000    0.00    0.000   1.00
2   0.000000    0.00    0.000   1.00
3   0.000000    0.00    0.000   1.00
4   0.000000    0.00    0.000   0.00
accuracy    0.250000    0.25    0.250   0.25
macro avg   0.066667    0.20    0.100   4.00
weighted avg    0.083333    0.25    0.125   4.00
```